# How to understand the tensorflow's Slice function？

Tags: tensorflow

Recently, I learned the code about RNN from the tutorials of tensorflow.Part code as below, while more information at https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent

```
outputs = []
    state = self._initial_state
    with tf.variable_scope("RNN"):
      for time_step in range(num_steps):
        if time_step > 0: tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
        (cell_output, state) = cell(inputs[:, time_step, :], state)#here!
        outputs.append(cell_output)
```

I just can't undetstand that how `inputs[:, time_step, :]`works,for example, what's these Args mean?
Your answer will be appreciated.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `input` is of shape `[d1, d2, d3]`, `time_step` is a natural integer below `d2`, and

```
output = inputs[:, time_step, :]
```

Then output is a matrix of shape `[d1, 1, d3]` such that

```
output[i, 0, j] = input[i, time_step, j]
```

It basically extracts the elements of input given by the indices given in the brackets, *":"* meaning  *"all of them on that dimension"*.

Comment: Sorry ,I just a beginner to StackOverFlow,and I only click the up arraw(there is not display cause I have reputation less than 15).now ,Accepted.Thanks